# Redirect 301 and Rewrite Rule Results in Query String being added

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I know there are some conflicts with my redirect and rewrite statements, but I haven't been able to find a solution.  I am not great with regular expressions.

Currently, I have this:

```
RewriteRule category_(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ category.php?brand_name=$1&bid=$2&stid=$3&lid=$4&did=$5&sid=$6&sort=$7
```

It results in a page that similar to this:

```
category_Jackets-1-2-3-4-5-6.html
```

I want to now for SEO purposes, redirect that page to:

```
category_Womens_Jackets-1-2-3-4-5-6.html
```

I tried putting:

```
Redirect 301 /category_Jackets-1-2-3-4-5-6.html category_Womens_Jackets-1-2-3-4-5-6.html
```

But it resulted in:

```
category_Womens_Jackets-1-2-3-4-5-6.html?brand_name=Jackets&bid=1&stid=2&lid=3&did=4&sid=5&sort=6
```

I have tried using variations of Rewrite rule and Redirect to try to solve this, but no luck so far.  I know the conflict is the issue, but I can't remove the original rewrite rule, or those pages would not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 301 will obviously redirect page, what exactly you need? please mention properly

Comment: I needed it not to add the query string.  I think the answer below is helping me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Redirect` and `RewriteRule` directives are part of 2 different modules (mod_alias and mod_rewrite) and both will get applied to the same URI at different points. So you're rewriting **AND** redirecting at the same time. You should just stick with mod_rewrite to redirect if you're employing rewriting.

```
RewriteRule ^category_Jackets-1-2-3-4-5-6\.html$ category_Womens_Jackets-1-2-3-4-5-6.html [L,R=301]
```

The `R=301` in the flags tells it to 301 redirect. You're going to want this **before** your other rule, and, your other rule is going to need to account for the `Womens` part.

Comment: I believe this worked, swore I had tried this method already, except I did not have the ^ at the beginning.  What exactly does that do?  Regardless, does appear to be working now, thanks for your help.